# How to fetch data from specific hours in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem with CosmosDB, which also allows some SQL queries.

I have a database that is being uploaded every hour with a new record.
I would like to fetch everything from the last day from 8PM to 8AM current day and another query from 8AM to 8PM the current day. I have a timestamp in the db in ISO format. How the potential query (or queries) would look like?

I achieved to fetch last 24h like this, **but I really want to stick to the time range 8PM-8AM and then 8AM-8PM, basically two shifts. Previous one and the current one.**

```
function getLast24hTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var a = date.setHours(-24);
    return a;
}
```

and then:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.time >= udf.getLastHourTime()
```

tl;dr Everyday I want to fetch specific hours range from the previous day (8pm-8am) + specific hours from the current day (8am-8pm). How.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in mysql you could do

the other shift is analog

> ```
> CREATE TABLE be (
>   `date` DATETIME
> );
>
> INSERT INTO be
>   (`date`)
> VALUES
>   ('2022-01-13 20:41:24'),
>   ('2022-01-13 21:41:24'),
>   ('2022-01-14 01:41:24'),
>   ('2022-02-14 09:41:24'),
>   ('2022-02-14 10:41:24');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `date` from be WHERE `date` >  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 20 HOUR
> ANd  `date` < CURDATE()  + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
> ```

> ```
> | date                |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2022-01-13 20:41:24 |
> | 2022-01-13 21:41:24 |
> | 2022-01-14 01:41:24 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=faee9e3d7c1895a6afcaea6513c99e48)*